# Create keyboard shortcut for Chrome OS to move to next sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, chrome-os

I really need to create a keyboard shortcut to move from one sheet to the next in Google Sheets in Chrome OS. In Mac this exists, but does not on Chrome OS. There is an extension called Shortcut Manager (Chrome web store) that allows you to create a javascript app to activate a shortcut, but I have no idea how to do this.

On a Mac the shortcuts are theses:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> → Move to next sheet (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> on a Mac)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> → Move to previous sheet (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> on a Mac)

It would be nice to have something simpler on Chrome OS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rubén It's borderline: the answer below is specific to Google Sheets. There is some overlap between sites.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato: You are right. I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that <kbd>Search</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> key combination on a Chromebook will go from one sheet to another.

You just have to make sure that the search button on the Chromebook is not set to Caps Lock (but rather to Search) and it will work perfectly. I found this out completely by accident. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 3):

Without installing a Chrome extension, you can use these three key combinations to go to the next sheet on Chrome OS.

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Display list of sheets)
2. **up/down** key (Highlight sheet)
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Go to sheet)

[Source](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en).

Comment: This does work, but it's a bit tedious. The thing is that I have about 40 sheets and I need to copy something to all of them, so even though this might work, it would still take me some time to use. We really need a faster way to move from one sheet to another. If there is no way, I will have to find a script to copy something to all 40 at once.